# How to convert an array to an ArrayList without warnings/errors?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, compiler-warnings

So, I have a bit of a problem. I'm trying to convert an array of integers (called `list`) to an `ArrayList` (called `arrList`). The code shown below works fine:

```
java.util.ArrayList arrList = new java.util.ArrayList(Arrays.asList(list));
```

However, when compiled there is one warning: the line above is reported as using "unchecked or unsafe operations."

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to dispose of this warning. Since this is a homework assignment, part of the criteria is to be warning-free. Is there any way I could convert the array to an ArrayList without warnings/errors?

Comment: Any reason you're not using generics? Oh, and it would readability if you didn't call an *array* variable `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `list` seems to be an array of `int` and not `Integer`, you need to loop over them. Try the following:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.length);
for (int i: list) {
  intList.add(i);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend adding the size to the `ArrayList`: `new ArrayList<Integer>(list.length);`

Comment: This is a silly way of avoiding the warning

Answer (score 50):

Ensure you are using the correct "Arrays" import. By default, my Eclipse will try to import "edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util". Make sure it is just the standard "java.util" version and you should do something like:

```
    String[] arr = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Comment: Wtf... thank you. The accepted answer is a joke btw, who would do that to avoid such a warning.

Comment: How do we stop Eclipse from choosing this unusual import by default?

Comment: This is incredible, that was my problem, LOL.

Answer (score 5):

```
Collections.addAll(targetList, sourceArray);
```

Try the above solution. It should work

Comment: `method addAll in class Collections cannot be applied to given types`

Answer (score 0):

If your answer is not restricted to one line only, the most dummy-proof way would be:

```
java.util.ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int x : arrList) {
    arrList.add(x);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**This warning is issued usually when you contruct Collection of raw type.** i.e.You don't define what type of objects it will contain.

```
java.util.ArrayList arrList = new java.util.ArrayList(Arrays.asList(list));// issues warning as you made ArrayList of raw type.
```

To overcome it , Just add object type in ArrayList declaration.

```
java.util.ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new java.util.ArrayList(Arrays.asList(list));
```